# What happens if I get currval from a sequence in Oracle from one application while another application is inserting at the same time?

Tags: oracle

Let's say I have an application (App1) that is inserting into a table and I want to grab the currval from the sequence

-and-

At the same time, another application (App2) inserts into the same table I'm currently working with from App1. Is my currval thread-safe? Will I get the currval for my insert in App1 or would it potentially give me the currval for the insert from App2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`currval` is defined to return the last value of the sequence that was given to your session.  Every session will have a different `currval`.  A different session getting the `nextval` of a sequence has no impact on your session's `currval`.  By the same token, your session's `currval` tells you nothing about what a different session will get if it asks for the `nextval`.

Comment: Is there some documentation somewhere that says this or do you just know this from experience?

Comment: @BrianTHannan - You can start here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm  The combination of `currval` being valid for a session only after you've called `nextval` in the current session and a sequence being accessed by multiple sessions concurrently without locking implies the rest of the behavior.