# Oracle sequence nextval and currval confusing

Tags: oracle, plsql

In my procedure I write this

```
INSERT INTO questions(id, value) VALUES(my_seq.NEXTVAL, p_question);

INSERT INTO DEPENDENCIES(parent_question_id, child_question_id)
VALUES (my_seq.CURRVAL, my_seq.NEXTVAL);
```

Let's say sequence's last value equals to 1. In this case I expect this result:

```
 my_seq.NEXTVAL = 2;
 my_seq.CURRVAL = 2;
 my_seq.NEXTVAL = 3;
```

But it inserts this:

```
 my_seq.NEXTVAL = 2;
 my_seq.CURRVAL = 3;
 my_seq.NEXTVAL = 3;
```

I would like to know why does oracle retrieve sequence value in this way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you had three separate statements :

1. nextval
2. currval
3. nextval

Then you would be correct.  But you only have two

1. nextval
2. currval and nextval

Currval and nextval are part of a single atomic step - currval does not get processed before nextval.

You'll need to use variables for this :

```
DECLARE
  l_parent_question_id     NUMBER ;
  l_child_question_id      NUMBER ;
BEGIN
  l_parent_question_id := my_seq.NEXTVAL ;

  INSERT INTO questions(id, value) VALUES(l_parent_question_id, p_question);

  l_child_question_id := my_seq.NEXTVAL ;

  INSERT INTO DEPENDENCIES(parent_question_id, child_question_id)
  VALUES (l_parent_question_id, l_child_question_id); 

END ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I fixed this problem like that:  **INSERT INTO DEPENDENCIES(
         parent_question_id,
         child_question_id
        ) VALUES (
         my_seq.CURRVAL-1,
         my_seq.NEXTVAL
        )** . It seems your solution more elegant than mine. I would like to know your opinion about my solution.

Comment: I would definitely avoid the currval-1 construct.  It works, sure (because CURRVAL returns the value for your session only - there's no danger that a different session will affect the value) but think about the poor developer who has to update your code in 2 years time.  They won't know what you intended here unless you put in a comment.  But by using variables it's really clear what you are trying to do - the code comments itself

Comment: Thank you so much, I understood. I will change it.

Comment: @ChristianPalmer "there's no danger that a different session will affect the value" - surely a different session could have called `nextval` in between the two calls in this session; there's no guarantee these two will get contiguous values? I'd avoid that construct because it won't always work - and it might be a long time before it actually doesn't, and then it will be really hard to figure out what has gone wrong and how to fix it...

Comment: @AlexPoole I am pretty sure that CURRVAL is session-specific.  That said I cannot find any proof (but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/36141582/6171686).  But I think we both agree we would not code any solution this way

Comment: @ChristianPalmer - yes it is, but in that context (the OP's comment) it is the same as the `nextval` in the same statement (as your answer explains). So the `nextval` in first insert in this session gets say 42; some other session increments the sequence; the `nextval` in the second insert in this session then gets 44. Within that statement `currval` is now also 44, so `currval-1` is 43 - not the expected/desired 42. And yes, we're agreeing it's not a good idea, I'm just adding that it's worse than your comment suggested *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole - you're absolutely right.  Just as well someone thinks these things through!

Answer (score 4):

Just to follow up on Christian's explanation, [this is the documented behaviour](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Sequence-Pseudocolumns.html#GUID-55228D7B-9CF1-4496-8524-3CD1DD4773FD):

> If any of these locations contains references to both `CURRVAL` and `NEXTVAL`, then Oracle increments the sequence and returns the same value for both `CURRVAL` and `NEXTVAL`.

The 'location' in this case is an item from the list preceding that, "each `INSERT` statement containing a `VALUES` clause".